# Part of Powerhell's pipeline being skipped

Tags: powershell, pipeline

Part of pipeline instruction is being skipped every 2nd iteration, getting/setting explicit variables works just fine. What am I missing here?

Please comment/uncomment sections at the bottom of the script to compare results in cfg.json.

```
param (
    [string]$JSONFname = "cfg.json",
    [string]$Iterations = 300
  )

Function GetCfgData {
    param (
      [string]$JSONFname = "cfg.json",
      [string]$Key = ""
    )
    if (-not (Test-Path $JSONFname)) {
      New-Item -Name $JSONFname > $null
      $JSONData = @{iteration = $Iterations}
      $JSONData | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File $JSONFname
    }
    Write-Host (Get-Content $JSONFname | ConvertFrom-Json).$Key
    return [string](Get-Content $JSONFname | ConvertFrom-Json).$Key
  }

  Function SetCfgData {
    param (
      [string]$JSONFname = "cfg.json",
      [string]$Key = "",
      [string]$Value = ""
    )
      $JSONData = Get-Content $JSONFname | ConvertFrom-Json
      $JSONData.$Key = $Value
      $JSONData | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File $JSONFname
  }

1..100 | foreach {
  # "skipped" case 1
  # GetCfgData -Key "iteration" | ForEach-Object { $val= [int]$_ - 1} | SetCfgData -Key "iteration" -Value $val

  # working case 2
  $iter = GetCfgData -Key "iteration" 
  SetCfgData -Key "iteration" -Value $([int]$iter -1)
}
```

Comment: You get order of evaluation wrong.

Comment: @PetSerAl Could you elaborate? I see no obvious mistake here.

Comment: `GetCfgData -Key "iteration" | ForEach-Object { Write-Host Second; $val= [int]$_ - 1} | SetCfgData -Key "iteration" -Value $(,$val; Write-Host First)`

Comment: Thank you for the hint @PetSerAl